# How to create barcode in Ubuntu via a GUI?

Tags: software-recommendation, barcode

I used `barcode` app which is a stand alone program to run the barcode library with CLI mode only.

So, What a good software GUI used to create barcode in Ubuntu 12.04.

I've come to `KBarcode` but it seems no version for Ubuntu 12.04

Also I come to `TBarCode/X` but the last version for Ubuntu was for Ubuntu 11.04

I don't want CLI tools I already used most of them before, I just want GUI.

I prefer not to use the LibreOffice extension since the app have to be used in some embedded environment and not preferred to install libroffice just for making barcode!

Comment: Its OK I read your comments, you can remove the paragraph for me from the question if you wish, you are correct I simply presented a list of options to try as I don't have the hardware to test them, so I get your point. Don't know who down voted or close voted without comments, that annoys me, don't see why this question should be downvoted.

Comment: @markkirby I like your sportsman soul friend , I'm going to remove that paragraph as you wish

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was extracted from another answer here:

> [Zint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/) is an open source Linux barcode generator which allows you
>   to encode data in over 30 types of barcode symbol. In this
>   documentation a barcode encoding method is termed a symbology and the
>   resulting barcode image is termed a symbol. The symbologies currently
>   supported by Zint are: Code 11, Standard Code 2 of 5, IATA Code 2 of
>   5, Industrial Code 2 of 5, Interleaved Code 2 of 5, Code 2 of 5 Data
>   Logic, ITF-14, Deutche Post Leitcode, Deutche Post Identcode, UPC-A,
>   UPC-E, EAN-2, EAN-5, EAN-8, EAN-13, UK Plessey, MSI Plessey, Telepen
>   Alpha, Telepen Numeric, Code 39, Extended Code 39, Code 93, PZN,
>   LOGMARS, Codabar, Pharmacode, Code 128, GS1-128, NVE-18, GS1 DataBar,
>   DataBar-14, DataBar Limited, DataBar Extended, Code 16k, PDF417,
>   MicroPDF417, Two-Track Pharmacode, PostNet, PLANET, Australia Post
>   4-State Symbols, RM4SCC, USPS OneCode, Data Matrix, QR Code, Maxicode,
>   Composite Symbols, FIM and Flattermarken. In addition Zint also
>   provides barcode stacking, colour options and a verification stage for
>   SBN, ISBN and ISBN-13 data. The aim of the Zint project is to provide
>   an open source API for encoding all public domain barcode symbologies

Zint also has a GUI, and if you have the `qt4` libraries installed when you compile it it will build and install.  It can then be run with `zint-qt`.  You should read the `INSTALL` file in the source code tarball from SourceForge to know more about building the software.

---

<sub>This was initially posted as part of an answer by [mark kirby](https://askubuntu.com/users/75060/mark-kirby), and was initially grabbed from [here](http://www.adams1.com/unix.html).  It was extracted and put here in its own answer at the request of the OP because they're picky about "No CLI Solutions" being in the answer they accept.  It is not a Community Wiki because I've added the additional prereqs and information about the GUI program that the software can contain/install/build</sub>

Comment: If you upvote this answer, please also upvote [mark kirby](http://askubuntu.com/users/75060/mark-kirby)'s [answer to this question as well](http://askubuntu.com/a/642677/10616) as I only extracted a tidbit from his answer, and he did all the research (and deserves all the credit)

Answer (score 19):

Here is a selection of Unix & Linux Barcode Programs I found.

These programs are CLI only, OP requested GUI

### [GNU-barcode](http://www.gnu.org/software/barcode/)

GNU Barcode is a tool to convert text strings to printed bars. It supports a variety of standard codes to represent the textual strings and creates postscript output.

Main features of GNU Barcode:

- Available as both a library and an executable program
- Supports UPC, EAN, ISBN, CODE39 and other encoding standards
- Postscript and Encapsulated Postscript output
- Accepts sizes and positions as inches, centimeters, millimeters
- Can create tables of barcodes (to print labels on sticker pages)

### [DATHO](http://www.datho.net/BARCODE/EDATHO.HTM)

Features

Availabe types of barcodes:
EAN13 and EAN8, EAN128, UPCa and UPCe, addon code 2- and 5-digit, Code39, Code93, CODE128, Interleaved 2 of 5, Industrial, Matrix, Codabar. Code 11, PZN, DBP-Barcodes

- horizontal and vertikal output
- automatic checksum-calculation
- different module sizes
- line with text in clear
- barcode and text in one line (= banding with matrix- and
  PCL3-printer)

### [iXBC](http://www.agosys.com/ixbc/)

The central software solution for bar code printing from SAP.
iXBC is the ideal barcode print supplement to SAP R/3 and mySAP for all SAP printing possibilities:

Direct printing from server - with nativ PCL or Postscript device from UNIX and Windows
Indirect printing - with SAPWIN device

Direct printing from server

You install it only once on the server and all PCL and PostScript printers on the network are immediately able to print barcodes - without hardware plugin in each printer and without middleware. AGOSYS offers this solution since 1998, as the world's first.

Product variants:

- iXBCserver  for UNIX Platforms
- AIX
- HP-UX
- Linux
- Solaris
- Tru-64
- iXBCwin for all Windows Platforms

All usual 1D and 2D Barcode types

- Code39
- 2of5 Interleaved
- Code128 A/B/C/Auto
- Codabar
- EAN128
- UCC128       EAN8/13
- UPC A/E
- PDF417
- DataMatrix
- OCR-B Font

### [On-Tap/UNIX](http://www.isdweb.com/Support/Downloads/index.htm)

On-Tap VMS or UNIX bar coding software runs as a stand alone program and directly translates (filters) your text into bar codes. Once On-Tap has bar coded your file, you can send it to any printer anywhere within your network.

On-Tap lets you print VMS or UNIX bar codes from within your existing applications in minutes. Simply place a special trigger character before and after the information you'd like to bar code. When you print, bar codes will appear in place of the information you've marked. It even lets you change the trigger characters and control the spacing around each bar code. No other bar code software has these flexible features.

### [Barcode studio](http://www.tec-it.com/en/download/barcode-studio/Default.aspx)

Barcode Studio is the ideal tool for barcode design and bar code creation. This barcode maker software supports all common linear codes, all 2D-Codes, GS1-DataBar/RSS and Composite Codes. Barcode Studio prints the bar codes on arbitrary printers or exports them as image.

### [libdmtx](http://www.libdmtx.org/)

Site was offline for maintenance, will add description later

### [Zint](https://www.zint.org.uk)

A barcode encoding library supporting over 50 symbologies including Code
128, Data Matrix, USPS OneCode, EAN-128, UPC/EAN, ITF, QR Code, Code    16k, PDF417, MicroPDF417, LOGMARS, Maxicode, GS1 DataBar, Aztec,    Composite Symbols and more.

Zint has a GUI, thanks to user @Thomas W.

Follow its build and install guides.
When done, run:

```
zint-qt
```

with an `&` at the end (to fork it to the background)

As a small extra, here is a libre office barcode plug in

### [Barcode](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/barcode)

A simple extension for creating UPC-A, EAN-13, ISBN, JAN,
Bookland Standard 2of 5, Interleaved 2 of 5, Code128 barcodes in LibreOffice Draw.

Comment: Indeed no one of what you list above meets my need, all of them is CLI unless the libreoffice extension which is not so useful in my case.

Comment: @Maythux um... Zint has a GUI you just need the qt4 libraries present at compile time

Comment: @Maythux I also found this, it is gui but says for QR code and I have no means of testings, so will just leave a comment for now, It is in repos `sudo apt-get install grencode` but says you need this .deb for GUI https://launchpad.net/qr-code-creator/ Also info page http://www.erickjohncuevas.com/news/finally-a-graphical-qr-code-creator-in-ubuntu/ Could be usefull

Comment: @ThomasW. I already installed it few hours ago but I didn't recognize such thing! How can I have it?

Comment: @markkirby QR code is not a barcode so it will not help in this case but thanks for help

Comment: @Maythux follow it's build and install guides.  When done, run `zint-qt` from either Alt+F2 or the command line with an `&` at the end (to fork it to the background)

Comment: @ThomasW. Ok that's it I already installed it before, but I didn't notice the `zint-qt` thanks, Added it as answer so I could accept it

Comment: @Maythux why not accept this answer here?  Since it is the one that pointed to zint

Comment: This answer is just copy/paste and it doesn't really answers my specifications, I just want GUI tool, I don't need all those CLI eventhat I gave him my upvote but it's not a valid answer for my question

Comment: @markkirby My apologies for snipping from your answer, but I gave a note that I also extracted it from your answer here.

Comment: @ThomasW. No problem I say the previous comments

Comment: Hey @markkirby - as it stands, this answer is a near-verbaitim copy of a work with a restrictive copyright that you have no license to share (assuming you're not the owner of adams1.com). It almost certainly has value here but could you reduce or transform it so it's more of your own work (and less of theirs). Fair use allows you *some* copying, but probably not this much.

Comment: @Oli Based on your comment I updated this answer to be my own work pulling information from the provided download sites instead.

Comment: Glabels seems like another potential alternative: https://blog.worldlabel.com/2009/printing-labels-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 5):

I use [Barcode extension](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/barcode) for LibreOffice.  Barcode is a simple extension for creating UPC-A, EAN-13, ISBN, JAN, Bookland Standard 2of 5, Interleaved 2 of 5, Code128 barcodes in LibreOffice Draw.

Comment: Isn't there a native app for this instead of using Libreoffice extension?!

Comment: I believe its Barcode, but its cli.

Comment: Unfortunately will no longer install in LibO 6.2. :(

Answer (score 2):

A good option for Linux users are web applications. If you want to create and print barcode labels with image/photo, title and text, you can take a look at the following free online barcode label generator:

### [www.megabarcode.com](https://www.megabarcode.com)

It works without registration and does not require any personal information.

Disclosure: I have developed this web application.

Answer (score 1):

Glabel can make barcode and qrcode, and can print them on labels

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple to **enconde** and **decode**: [QtQR](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/qtqr)

Comment: broken link, not detailed at all

Comment: QtQR is for QR codes, not for barcodes.